# Can I use reflection to get the value name and values from EF SqlQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

if I have something like this

```
 var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<object>("SELECT GroupID, GoupName, GroupValue FROM Group").ToList();
```

as  you can see I use object because I do not have a specific class i can bind it to.

is there any way I can get the info and value of columns from results.

I tried using Reflection and it did not work

```
 Type type = result.GetType();
 FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
 foreach (var field in fields) // Loop through fields
 {
     string name = field.Name;
 }
```

is there any way to do it thanks

Comment: Total and utter guess, haven't tried it... does it work if you GetProperties instead of Fields? Also you could try some binding flags. Again if I was in any way sure about this, I would be putting in an answer not a comment!

Comment: I tried it as well it does the same think as field

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like there's a way to do it - one thing, your `result` isn't a single object, but rather a `InternalSqlNonSetQuery`, which contains a collection of objects. In your case, since your generic parameter is `object`, you get totally empty `System.Object` objects, with no parameters.

I was hoping `Dictionary<string, object>` would work, but no such luck.

If you know the field names and types in advance, even if you don't define a type in the code, you can define a type at runtime using the technique found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mazhou/archive/2011/09/21/use-dynamic-type-in-entity-framework-4-1-sqlquery-method.aspx), but that may not be what you're looking for. (If this link ever dies, basically what it's doing is building a brand new type using Reflection Emit, and using that as the result type, but it's not a trivial amount of code).